# How to merge multiple column into 1 cell with linebreak/new line in Google Sheets?

Tags: google-sheets, concatenation, array-formulas, google-sheets-formula, textjoin

[image]

Hi,
I want to ask is it possible to merge more than 1 cell result into one cell, like the result shown in B10 with formula?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can do it easily like this:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(TEXTJOIN(CHAR(10), 1, H16:H25))
```

[image: 0]

Comment: NOTE: char(10) == '\n'

Answer (score 0):

Please try:

```
=C4&char(10)&C5&char(10)&C6
```